# Maximum call size exceed express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, routes, joi

When I hit API on my nodejs application it hits my API multiple times and I get maximum call stack size exceed error. The structure was created by the previous developer. I think the routes are the cause that it is hitting the API multiple times. here is the directory structure :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awb7V.png)

```js
So every folder has its index.js file that imports its routes like this :


import common from './Common';
import investor from './Investor';
import vendor from './Vendor';
import admin from './Admin';
import propertyManager from './PropertyManager';
/*********** Combine all Main Routes ********************/
export default [...common, ...investor, ...admin, ...vendor, ...propertyManager];




and single route file under these folder looks like this


import express from 'express';
import { createValidator } from 'express-joi-validation';
import Joi from 'joi';

import { isUserSignedIn } from '../../src/utilities/universal';
import { updateAdminSettings } from '../../src/modules/Admin/controller';

const app = express();
const validator = createValidator({ passError: true });

const coupon = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.string().required().label('Unique Id '),
  investorYearlyDiscount: Joi.number().min(0).max(30).optional().label('Investor Yearly Discount '),
  pmYearlyDiscount: Joi.number().min(0).max(30).optional().label('Property Manager Yearly Discount '),
  additionalPropertyAmount: Joi.number().min(1).optional().label('Additional Property Count'),
});

app.put(
  '/Admin/settings',
  validator.body(coupon, {
    joi: { convert: true, allowUnknown: false },
  }),
  isUserSignedIn,
  updateAdminSettings
);

export default app;
```

Comment: Could you provide the call stack?

Comment: Hi Strings,  In the Node Module router I have printed the path in layer file and it is showing me multiple times my router is hitting or searching for that particular API. Please see below for reference.

Comment: path ---- /payment/checkout
path ---- /api/payment/checkout
path ---- /payment/checkout
path ---- /payment/checkout
path ---- /api/payment/checkout
path ---- /payment/checkout
path ---- /payment/checkout
path ---- /api/payment/checkout
path ---- /payment/checkout
path ---- /payment/checkout
path ---- /api/payment/checkout

Comment: Something that wraps around your API is possibly creating a recursive loop, but with the size of your project it isn't possible to identify that.  Can you put a break point on the API call, get the call stack from your debugger, then continue to the breakpoint for a second time, and then get the next stack trace

Comment: JOI also has an abortearly flag that might be worth investigating as that may stop the recursion if it is occurring during the validation

Comment: ok let me get back to you on this and will see if joi is making any trouble with this

Comment: I don't check stack overflow every day... Have you made any progress?